# Mapping DI dependencies with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to map out all the DI that's happening in a large solution using Roslyn. My goal is to get a tree I can then visualize. I've managed to get so far as to parse the syntax trees to find all classes and interfaces and their methods, along with the projects they're defined in, but now I find myself stuck.

What is the right approach to do this sort of analysis with Roslyn? Do I walk every method invocation in every method, looking for Autofac Register calls? That seems both incredibly awkward and error-prone. I was hoping the semantic API would be of use here, but I can't find a good way to tackle that either.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "walking" a method invocation; can you clarify?  If you want a list of all the method invocations in a translation unit, it's pretty straightforward to express that as a query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all calls to a particular method, the easiest way is to use the Workspace layer `SymbolFinder` type.

First look up the `ISymbol` of interest, by using `Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName` to get the type, followed by `GetMembers("methodName")` to get the method.  Then you can call `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync` to find all callers.

Comment: I guess my real question is whether that's the correct way to identify DI dependencies? In the case of autofac, everything is ultimately a Register<>().As<>() call, should i be looking for those to map things?

Comment: It seems reasonable, but I don't know enough about Autofac or your goals to say.for sure

Comment: I am working on something similar and am running into an issue with `FindReferencesAsync ` where it is not finding all of the references. I have three projects, A(VB) B(C#) and C(C#). A relies on B and C, B relies on C. FindReferencesAsync finds references to C that exist in A but not references to B that exist in A. Do you have any idea what might cause that?